# Streaming videos with Django

Tags: python, django, apache, video, video-streaming

I have a Django application and I want to create a UI from which users will be able to play videos. Videos are dynamically generated and saved on my web server.
I am running a Django application on an Apache web-server through `mod_wsgi`. It takes a long time to buffer/load video; please suggest how can I improve it. I am using Ubuntu Server with 16 GB RAM, quad core processor and 1 TB SSD.

Comment: Hvae you considered using HLS streaming?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using a cloud provider such as Amazon Web Services.

Have a look at [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html), this will help you get your videos from django up to AWS. You'll store your video's on [Amazon's S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), then, if you have an international audience use [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to stream. You can use RTMP to do this (that's "proper" streaming as apposed to incremental download while playing).

On the browser side you probably just want to use the `<video>` tag (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)). You'll be saving the source attribute of the video (a reference to the location of the video on cloudfront) on your django model and then adding it into your templates.

Comment: I am using AWS instance. I don't want to use S3 service. Can I install any free streaming server on my AWS instance ?

Comment: I'm sure you can, I just dont know what's available. Heard people talk about wowza. And I think nginx has a rmtp module.